# How can bypass routing and manually select a controller?

Tags: asp.net-core

What I'm trying to do is look directly at the incoming web request and manually select a controller to handle it. So far, I have created a custom implementation of IControllerFactory, but it seems that this runs after routing. Since the requests that are coming in don't match a route registered with MVC, it immediately goes to 404.

What I'm trying to figure out is how I can skip the routing portion straight to IControllerFactory step.

This sounds super odd, but I'm doing a proof of concept on creating routes at runtime. The idea is that, at runtime, I can download and load an assembly that has some controllers in it (i.e. a plugin) and then attempt register the route without restarting the service. I have most of it worked out I think, but I'm trying to figure out the routing part and it seemed easiest to simply grab the request and manually select the controller.

I've looked into implementing IRouter and then using app.UseRouter(myRouter) but I couldn't quite find what I was looking for.

Suggestions?

Comment: did you tried to call your method in configureservices at first line doesn't it resolves your issue?

Comment: What about a middleware? I found this interesting, but also without not much idea on how to implement.. will be paying attention :). Do you happen to have what you accomplished so far in a github repo? The ASP.NET Core team are quite active over Twitter.. so you could also ask there and point to either this or to the sample repo.

Comment: To whomever voted to close: explain please or you are equally in violation.

@jpgrassi I thought about middleware, but I don't know what needs to be done to bind it to a controller and didn't see anything. Tried adding route data which didn't work. I'll push to public repo once it's a bit more legible.

Comment: @HamzaHaider I'm not sure what you're trying to say. If you're talking about configuring routes on UseMvc, as I said, that does not meet the requirements on how I'm trying to make this function.